# Can not reset the axes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a circle and a randomly distributed set of points inside it. AFAIK, one can add as many as figures he wants to an `ax` object. So, here is my approach:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.uniform(1,5,size=1000)
theta = np.random.uniform(0.55*np.pi,1.2*np.pi,size=1000)
y = [i*np.tan(j) for i,j in zip(x,theta)]

xx = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=1000)
yy = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=1000)

for i in range(len(xx)):
    if xx[i]>yy[i]:
        xx[i],yy[i] = yy[i],xx[i]

R = 5

xxx = [j*R*np.cos(2*np.pi*i/j) for i,j in zip(xx,yy)]
yyy = [j*R*np.sin(2*np.pi*i/j) for i,j in zip(xx,yy)]

circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 5, color='b', fill=False)
scatt = plt.scatter(yyy,xxx)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.add_artist(circle)
ax.add_artist(scatt)

plt.ylabel("scatter")
plt.xlabel("Data")

plt.show()
```

But the interpreter returns the following error:

> ValueError: Can not reset the axes.  You are probably trying to re-use
>   an artist in more than one Axes which is not supported

What's my silly mistake?!

Comment: you might have got the error on line `ax.add_artist(scatt)`

Comment: @ksai: That line just adds another "plot" to the defined `ax`, doesn't it?

Comment: I tried commenting out both `artist` lines. I still get two plot. Let me look into this

Comment: What's the output that you're expecting ?

Comment: @ksai: I need to have both `scatt` and `circle` in just one `ax`. Like a unified plot.

Comment: I've never tried adding things to axes that way.  You might try calling [`ax.scatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) and [`ax.add_patch(Circle(...))`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.add_patch.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.add_patch) instead of creating them on their own axes and then calling `add_artist` (at least for the scatter axes)

Comment: @Roboticist Sorry, I wasn't clear about which `Circle`, see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

x = np.random.uniform(1,5,size=1000)
theta = np.random.uniform(0.55*np.pi,1.2*np.pi,size=1000)
y = [i*np.tan(j) for i,j in zip(x,theta)]

xx = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=1000)
yy = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=1000)

for i in range(len(xx)):
    if xx[i]>yy[i]:
        xx[i],yy[i] = yy[i],xx[i]

R = 5

xxx = [j*R*np.cos(2*np.pi*i/j) for i,j in zip(xx,yy)]
yyy = [j*R*np.sin(2*np.pi*i/j) for i,j in zip(xx,yy)]

#circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 5, color='b', fill=False)
#scatt = plt.scatter(yyy,xxx)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#ax.add_artist(circle)
#ax.add_artist(scatt)

ax.scatter(yyy,xxx)
ax.add_patch(mpl.patches.Circle((0, 0), 5, color='b', fill=False))

plt.ylabel("scatter")
plt.xlabel("Data")

plt.axis('equal')       # Added, optional :)

plt.show()
```

Produces

[image: Overlayed plots]

The only difference is I created a single axes object (through `plt.subplots()`), called axes methods [`ax.scatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) and [`ax.add_patch(Circle(...))`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.add_patch.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.add_patch) to draw on it.

My guess is that the `plt.__` methods you were calling were creating their own separate axes and then your attempt at "merging" them with `add_artist` was causing the error.